# Java : Casting from Double to integer

Tags: java, casting, integer, double

For the method setKVP  the parameter required  is an Integer   value

```
public void setkVp(int d){
   kVp=d;       
}
```

But the following code produces Double value, how can i make sure that  e.setkVp gives out integer Value instead of Double

```
s="KVP ";
if (ln.contains(s))
   {
      int i=ln.indexOf("=");
      if (i>0){
         e.setkVp(parse(ln.substring(i+2,ln.length()-3))).intvalue();
      }
```

parse.. Parses the value of KVP from CSV file.

Comment: Use Integer.valueOf (value) or cast it to int with (int) value

Comment: `(int)doubleValue` - primitive cast

Comment: And be sure not to use any precision. If needed use `Math.ceil(doubleValue)` or `Math.floor(doubleValue)`

Comment: What does `parse()` do? Why haven't you posted it? Presumably it returns a `Double?` or a `double?` Which? Why? What's your intent? What's the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`e.setkVp(parse(ln.substring(i+2,ln.length()-3))).intvalue();` should be formatted as 
`e.setkVp(parse(ln.substring(i+2,ln.length()-3)).intvalue());` else you do `intValue()` on the return value of `setkVp(int)` which is void.

Comment: I am incurring an error which says Cannot resolve intvalue();

Comment: If your `parse()` method return a Double, using `parse(foo).intValue()` (mind the camelCase) should return an `int`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#intValue%28%29

Comment: Sadly, i am incurring the same error, i have called necessary Libraries ,but still i am incurring same error ...Which states cannot resolve intValue();

Comment: Which version of Java are you ?